# Register inline service worker in web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, service-worker, web-notifications

I'm toying with adding web push notifications to a web app hosted with apps script. To do so, I need to register a service worker and I ran into an error with a cross-domain request. Raw content is hosted from `*.googleusercontent.com` while the script URL is `script.google.com/*`.

I was able to successfully create an inline worker using [this post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) on creating inline URLs created from a `blob` with the script. Now I'm stuck at the point of registering the worker in the browser.

The following model works:

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Display the worker status -->
<div id="log"></log>
```

**Service Worker**

```js
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
    self.postMessage('msg from worker');
  };
  console.log('[Service Worker] Process started');

  })
</script>
```

**Inline install**

```js
<script>
  function log(msg) {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    document.querySelector("#log").appendChild(fragment);
  }

  // Create the object with the script
  var blob = new Blob([ document.querySelector("#worker").textContent ]);

  // assign a absolute URL to the obejct for hosting
  var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    log("Received: " + e.data);
  }

  worker.postMessage('start');
  // navigator.serviceWorker.register(worker) this line fails
</script>
```

`navigator.serviceWorker.register(worker);` returns a `400: Bad HTTP response code` error.

Can inline workers be installed? Or do all installed workers have to come from external scripts?

Answer (score 7):

It's worth noting that Web Workers and Service Workers, which are used with push notifications, are different (see [this SO response to read about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38634315/1027723)).

According to MDN Service Workers [require a script URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#Parameters). In Google Apps Script you could serve a service worker file with something like:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var file = e.parameter.file;
  if (file == 'service-worker.js'){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('service-worker.js').getContent())
                         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  }
}
```

But as in [this example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzZ6TORJWCfcXAS103pVCf90RlqT-6ptSemUYhac_e3YTADNgo/exec) ([source code here](https://script.google.com/d/1Yo_pfuRwLvcN93gmz4IkT9W8JcCQv2i4BRXCN5bUW2CY9Ep-2LDeOMJs/edit?usp=sharing)) because of the way web apps are served you'll encounter the error:

> SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.

There was a [proposal for Foreign Fetch for Service Workers](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5684130679357440)  but it's still in draft.

Comment: About Foreign Fetch, it was recently removed from Service Workers. See https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/pull/1207 and the related issue at https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1188