# Transform Google apps script webapp into progressive wa

Tags: google-apps-script, progressive-web-apps

i want to get more accessible my webabb deployed on Google Apps Script.
I tried to do this adding an embedded manifest:

```
 <link rel="manifest" href='data:application/manifest+json,
{
    "name":"SharePoint Title",
    "short_name":"SP Title",
    "description":"description",
    "start_url":"get_script_url",
    "icons":[
        {
            "src":"icon_url",
            "sizes":"144x144","type":"image/png"
        }
    ],
    "background":"rgb(255,0,0)",
    "theme_color":"rgb(255,255,255)",
    "display":"fullscreen"
}'>
```

and this js code (as shown in [https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen):

```
let deferredPrompt;
    const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-button');
    addBtn.style.display = 'none';

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    deferredPrompt = e;
    // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
    addBtn.style.display = 'block';

    addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
        addBtn.style.display = 'none';
        // Show the prompt
        deferredPrompt.prompt();
        // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
        deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
            if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
            console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
            } else {
            console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
            }
            deferredPrompt = null;
        });
    });
    });
```

But when I can't load the page from any mobile device: Google returns an error.

Does somebody know how could I solve the problem?
Thanks a lot

Comment: "Google returns an error.' - I don't see the error? If you share that someone may be able to help. Also - It works on desktop with no console errors , but not mobile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to develop Progressive web app with google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458858/how-to-develop-progressive-web-app-with-google-app-script)