# build real time dashboard using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I want to be able to update my web app constantly (in real time) such that anytime there's an update on my Google Sheet (via a webhook configured using apps script's `doGet` function), the same is shown in the HTML dashboard that I've built.

I don't need help with setting up my sheet, or the webhook or the HTML dashboard - I have all of that already setup.

I do need help / advise on how can I **update** my HTML dashboard (web app) any time there's an update either on my `doGet` function or on the sheet (that part doesn't really matter).

The best example would be the way Google Analytics realtime dashboard changes, every time there's a new user who lands on your website.

PS. I know I'm supposed to share some code but everything I have has nothing to do with what I actually want; hope that's clear but should there be a need for any of you to see my code/sheet, I'd be happy to create a dummy version.

Comment: You can’t really initiate communication from the server to the client so you will have to poll the server from the client. Since you want the web app to be a dashboard then that should work OK for you because the client will have to be on all the time. So you can use the client timer to run a polling function that initiates communication between the client and server and asks the question basically what’s happening then the server can respond and return something to the success handler. Take a look at client server communication in the documentation guide section.

Comment: Ideally you'd want to use Web Push notifications to achieve this, but that requires Service Workers which are not supported in GAS Web Apps(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47167978/6586255). So you have to fall back on "polling" as suggested by @Cooper

Comment: You might be able to user [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) but its not supported by some browsers (IE and Edge).

Comment: May be you can check on the Bruce Mc Pherson site there is some examples http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/pseudobinding on my side I implemented a kind of realtime by querying the backend each second, on this app for emo https://app.ez34.net/ezplus/

Comment: Thank you so much, all. I think I have all the insights I needed to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use:

- `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` which is a JavaScript, asynchronous, [Client-side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) that allows you to interact with server side functions (references could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)).
- `setInterval` function to invoke the aforementioned client-side API at a frequency you see fit

  - 3000/3500 milliseconds is what I've been using so far and the [service quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) don't specifically talk about *its* limitations

## Server side

This is pretty much the code that gets written in the **code.gs** part of the script; where all your functions reside that interact perhaps with your Spreadsheets or act as the webhook

## Client side

That's the code that runs from your ***.html** file and, post loading, on your web browser. This is where you get to use the "asynchronous" API

## Example

In my [dummy setup](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzm_yn_6Vsllcn6PTBfpCj0fOPUeVKkg3jWLo8CJ3v797cRgSd6/exec), I'm -

1. Fetching random quotes from [thesimpsonsquoteapi](https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me)
2. Displaying a timer that changes every second

### Code.gs (server-side code)

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle('Realtime Data');
}

function randomQuotes() {
  var baseURL = 'https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes';
  var quotesData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  var quote;
  var imageURL;
  if (quotesData.getResponseCode() == 200 || quotesData.getResponseCode() == 201) {
    var response = quotesData.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(response)[0];
    quote = data["quote"];
    imageURL = data["image"];
  } else {
    quote = 'Random Quote Generator is broken!';
    imageURL = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Sad_Face_Emoji_large.png?v=1480481055';
  }
  var randomQuote = {
    "quote": quote,
    "imageTag": '<img class="responsive-img" src="' + imageURL + '">'
  }
  return randomQuote;
}

function getTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  return now;
}
```

### Index.html (client-side code)

*I'm only highlighting the relevant aspects of the code*

The following fetches random quotes every 10 seconds (10000 ms)

```
<script>
    function onSuccess1(quotedata) {
        var quoteactual = document.getElementById('quote');
        quoteactual.innerhtml = quotedata.quote;
        var quoteimg = document.getElementById('quoteImage');
        quoteimg.innerhtml = quotedata.imagetag;
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("getting quote...")
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onsuccess1).randomQuotes();
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

This fetches time every 1 second (1000 ms)

```
<script>
    function onSuccess2(now) {
        var div = document.getElementById('time');
        var today = new Date();
        var time = today.getHours() + " : " + today.getMinutes() + " : " + today.getSeconds();
        div.innerhtml = time;
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("getting time...")
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onsuccess2).getTime();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

You can access the entire script on [my github repository](https://github.com/schoraria911/google-apps-script/tree/master/Real-time%20Dashboard) or [make a copy from the original script](https://script.google.com/d/1vrW0lVEiAUvNqpVAKGZuI847grDsyv9aqJLNu07wusnCPzHdD_G-3JYn/edit?usp=sharing).

### Output

The image here is supposed to change every 10s and timer, every 1s

[image: real-time]

The browser console log can be viewed here -

[image: real-time console]

I wrote [this article](https://script.gs/build-a-real-time-dashboard-web-app-using-google-script-run-api/) a couple weeks ago that outlines most aspects of what everyone has been answering/commenting so far but I'm hoping my explanation here helps as well.

Comment: Wow! Oddly enough, this article didn't come up on my search results (maybe I wasn't looking for the right set of keywords) but this great! Perfect in almost all sense of what I needed. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

In order to accomplish real-time performance to your dashboard, you would need to use Web Push notifications as the user @Dimu Designs claimed, or keep an open websocket connection between the client and your webapp. However, I'm afraid that for the time being, none of these solutions are supported.

The only solution that's left would be to employ polling: The HTML served to the client would have Javascript code embedded to it that would set up a cron-like function that issues a request to your webapp every X seconds (see [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)) and updates your dashboard's content.

Bear in mind that this solution will involve sending many HTTP requests to your webapp, which will have the following downsides:

1. An increased amount of bandwidth consumption.
2. A non-real time dashboard, which will lag up to the X seconds determined to be the refresh rate.
3. Upon sending a large number of requests in a short-time period, you may experience rate limitations. For more information about this, you can check the quotas [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Comment: I know polling is perhaps not the best route but I guess that's what we have to look forward to, at the moment. Thanks for sharing your response though.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer from @Cooper, @Dimu Designs and @carlesgg97. But I also also suggest an alternative solution via Google Sites and/or Google Sheets.

Dont know if you are willing to pass your HTML dashboard to Sites (it does support inserting HTML) , but if you do, you can insert the graphs directly from Google Sheets (or create graphs in there), even as tables, and they would automatically update (not embed ones though). [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs]

Optionally, you can create graphs in Google Sheets and then publish them [https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1047436?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en], which would provide you with a link you use in HTML.

Comment: It's an alternative solution that can be implemented relatively fast. however I only warn to choose carefully between old and new google sheets. The old version still gives you more control over the HTML. the New Sites is more optimized in auto for mobile devices.  Alternatively, it might be viable to create a site with the needed elements, and then link them to the site OP has separately.

Comment: Thank for sharing your insights on this.